# ORDER BY WITH DISTINCT IN SQL

Tags: sql

I have query like :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Format(partycaseassociatedparty.assigneddate, 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS [*Assigned Date],
                Format(partycaseassociatedparty.releaseddate, 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS [*Released Date]
FROM   dbo.partycaseassociatedparty AS PartyCaseAssociatedParty
WHERE  partycaseassociatedparty.programid = 1
ORDER  BY [*assigned date] DESC
```

Here [*Assigned Date] is in MM/dd/yyyy format so while sorting(order by) it will sort based on MM/dd/yyyy but I need to sort based on yyyy/MM/dd. How to achieve this here?

Comment: Order BY PartyCaseAssociatedParty.AssignedDate

Comment: This looks like an MS Access or SQL Server query.  Why is it tagged "mysql"?

Comment: it is showing error like "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified."

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY  FORMAT(PartyCaseAssociatedParty.AssignedDate,'yyyy/MM/dd') DESC
```

Comment: it is showing error like "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified."

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `distinct`, use `group by`:

```
SELECT Format(pcap.assigneddate, 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS [*Assigned Date],
       Format(pcap.releaseddate, 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS [*Released Date]
FROM   dbo.partycaseassociatedparty AS pcap
WHERE  pcap.programid = 1
GROUP BY Format(pcap.assigneddate, 'MM/dd/yyyy'), Format(pcap.releaseddate, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
ORDER BY max(pcap.assigneddate) DESC;
```

When you use `group by`, you can use an aggregation function in the `order by` clause.

Comment: DISTINCT is needed in the query.

Comment: @Saritha.S.R . . . The `group by` does the same thing.

Comment: Thats correct but I am generating the query automatically so distinct will come. Is there any way to do the same with distinct?

Comment: @Saritha.S.R . . . I don't think so.  You can do this by adding a third column to the output and ordering by that.